# SQL Where Clause - creating field when met

Tags: sql, insert, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Beginner here.....

I am creating a select statement with many "where" & "or" clauses, but I would like to create a single field/column when that where clause is met, for easy filtering.

```
select * from "STG_ADDRESS_MATCH" where 
   trim(lower(crm_salutation)) not like trim(lower(cons_title))  OR
   trim(lower(CRM_FIRST_NAME)) not like trim(lower(CONS_FIRST_NAME)) OR
   trim(lower(CRM_LAST_NAME)) not like trim (lower(CONS_LAST_NAME)) OR
   trim(lower(CRM_STREET1)) not like trim(lower(CONS_STREET1))
```

So, there would be a single field with "Salutation" for if the first condition is met, and then "First_Name" for the second condition being met, etc.

[image: Example Output in Yellow]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question doesn't include enough useful detail for us to help you. Check out [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and the importance of a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). After that, [Start Here](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to edit your question as needed.

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `NOT LIKE` here? Also, is your [Collation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation?view=sql-server-2017) case sensitive? If not, you don't need `LOWER`. Additionally, if you don't have any *leading* spaces your don't need `TRIM`. In fact, you don't need `TRIM` at all if you are using `LIKE`. I'm not real sure what you are trying to accomplish with your question, but it sounds like you are trying to find a cleaner way to write this, which could over complicate it.

Comment: Each Boolean statement can copied as-is from your WHERE clause and placed into your SELECT clause.  This will produce a column whose value is '1' when the condition is true, or '0' when it is false.  (Don't forget to name the columns, and separate them with commas and not 'OR')

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask.   This is a good guide:   https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: select * from "STG_ADDRESS_MATCH" 
    where    ltrim(rtrim((lower(crm_salutation))) not in ( ltrim(rtrim((lower(cons_title))))  OR
       ltrim(rtrim((lower(CRM_FIRST_NAME)))) not like ltrim(rtrim((lower(CONS_FIRST_NAME)))) OR
       ltrim(rtrim((lower(CRM_LAST_NAME)))) not like ltrim(rtrim( (lower(CONS_LAST_NAME)))) OR
       ltrim(rtrim((lower(CRM_STREET1)))) not like ltrim(rtrim((lower(CONS_STREET1)))) )
... I have edited your code plz have a look and suggest if this is what your looking for. Whatever you filter on in where can be made into a CASE statement filter as well per RyanB

Comment: Check if case when conditions helps for you.